# Prime31 Facebook Android Plugin of Unity

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, prime31

I have developed an app for ios by unity, and tried to transfer it to android platform. Hence I have to reimport all the prime31 plugins I have bought, substituting the ios version to the android version. However, after importing all the plugins and set up the environment, only the android facebook plugin from prime31 has some problems. And the problem is strange, even for the demo scene itself:

For old version plugin, I can receive the sessionopenedevent, however, for facebook login, if we close the facebook log in pop-out by clicking the small cross (or press the back button), and access readwithpermissions again, it will hang :(. A non-similar hang happens when users open the "invite friends" dialog and close it by that small cross (fine by clicking the "cancel" button), or clicking the back button on phone. Any clues ?

After the first few trials, I decide to upgrade it to the latest version, but after that the facebook log-in pop out doesn't lead to sessionopenedevent, and the session is always invalid, no session token generated, hence no way to test further.

I have checked the AndroidManifest.xml file, set up the facebook native android app in the way described by prime31, and generated the key hash for facebook app. Burning whole night already, anyone any clue ?

Thanks....